# concatenate results of a sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to figure if it is possible to concatenate the results of a SQL query if the output has more than one value

For example: If the below query returns more than one result

```
select * from employee
```

Output:

```
emp1
emp2
emp3
```

I want the results to show as

> emp1, emp2, emp3

Comment: That depends if he want those in three separate fields, or if he wants one field showing "emp1, emp2, emp3", in which case it would be a custom aggregate. He needs to be a little more explicit in his question.

Comment: @user3324344..Use PIVOT and later you can concatenate using , in between

Comment: Sorry eidylon for not being more explicit, I wanted the results like you mentioned "emp1, emp2, emp3"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "listagg"

Example:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(columnname, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY columname)
```

Hope it resolves the issue!

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT LISTAGG(empname,',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY empname) FROM emp;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `listagg` function

```
select listagg(first_name,',') within group(order by employee_id) from employees;
```

I am using the employees table of  HR schema provided in oracle 11g release 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the xmlelement function.

```
SELECT
   RTRIM (XMLAGG (XMLELEMENT (E, EMPLOYEENAME|| ', ')).EXTRACT ('//text()'), ',') ENAMES
FROM
   EMPLOYEE;
```